# Adding a custom image onto a Navigation Drawer's center

Tags: android, android-custom-view, navigation-drawer

I'm experimenting for the first time with Android's Navigation Drawer. I think it is a very elegant way to provide an application menu. However, showing my prototype to some friends, it seems that it is not quit intuitive to search for a menu i) on the top left corner respectively ii) on the left side of the screen.

To provide a "user hint" for case i), I added a custom image by creating an ActionBarDrawerToggle. This results in following design of the title bar (the little arrow is the cutom image, while the red star is the application icon):

[image]

Now while developping, I thought this is quite obvious, but apparantly I'm wrong :). So as a second idea, to support a user to find option ii) described below, I tried to figure out how to add a further image at a specific place, which I want to explain with following image:

[image]

Don't look at the design itself in the first place, but following: the image must be placed outside of the "view bounds" (when the navigation menu is hidden), and also exceed the navigation panel itself on the right side (always). Is this in any way possible without customize the entire navigation panel? I really wonder why I can't find much about this idea, since I think it is a very nice option to provide for the user (as long as the arrow don't disturbs the application usage)

Comment: google maps does something similar except they dont move the image with the drawer. They just put a "handle" to grab to show there is a drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't actually tested it with Android's Navigation Drawer,
did you try putting an imageview in your activity's layout? The image would be placed in the middle vertically and on parent left horizontally. I believe this would work (i.e. the image will get pushed when you open the drawer. As an improvement you could also change the image itself in the drawer's callbacks, so that you have an arrow pointing right when the drawer is closed and an arrow pointing left when the drawer is open.
Hope it helps.

Comment: You mean to put an ImageView with a higher z-value on top of the activity and handle scroll events? That sounds like a lovely hack :)